# Conflict between setTimeout and clicking outside the element detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, conflict, slide

I have the below code. It slides a mobile menu in, has a timeout function to only allow clicks in 500ms to prevent excessive clicks. It also closes back when user clicks outside the menu area. These two functions at the bottom of script are conflicting with each other. This only happens on a responsive site in a special case - if I click outside the menu area on first page load when mobile menu is still hidden, and then shrink the browser window, the menu shows up as already slid in.

```
var togglerWidth = jQuery('#mobile-menu-toggler').css('min-width'); //get width of toggler

//Slide left function
var slideLeft = function () {
    var menuWidth = jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile').width(); //get width of main menu
    jQuery('#mobile-menu-toggler').animate({
        width: menuWidth
    }, // what property we are animating
    500, // how fast we are animating
    'swing', // the type of easing
    function () { // the callback    
    });

    jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile').animate({
        right: "0px"
    }, // what property we are animating
    500, // how fast we are animating
    'swing', // the type of easing
    function () { // the callback 
    });
}

//Slide Right Function
var slideRight = function () {
    var menuWidth = jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile').width(); //get width of main menu
    jQuery('#mobile-menu-toggler').animate({
        width: togglerWidth
    }, // what property we are animating
    500, // how fast we are animating
    'swing', // the type of easing
    function () { // the callback    
    });

    jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile').animate({
        right: -menuWidth
    }, // what property we are animating
    500, // how fast we are animating
    'swing', // the type of easing
    function () { // the callback     
    });
}

var activate = function () { //switch to 'active-menu' class
    jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile, #mobile-menu-toggler').addClass('active-menu');
}

var deactivate = function () { //switch back to 'inactive-menu' class
    jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile, #mobile-menu-toggler').removeClass('active-menu').addClass('inactive-menu');
}

jQuery("#mobile-menu-toggler").click(function () {
    jQuery("#mobile-menu-toggler").unbind('click');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('inactive-menu');
    jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile').toggleClass('inactive-menu');
    jQuery("#mobile-menu-wrap").prop("disabled",true);
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('inactive-menu')) {
        slideRight();
        deactivate();
    } else {
        slideLeft();
        activate();
    }

//*************THIS FUNCTION HAS A CONFILCT WITH THE ONE BELOW****************
setTimeout(function(){setFunction()},500); //
});

var setFunction=function(){
jQuery("#mobile-menu-toggler").bind('click',function () {
    jQuery("#mobile-menu-toggler").unbind('click');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('inactive-menu');
    jQuery('#mainmenu-mobile').toggleClass('inactive-menu');
    jQuery("#mobile-menu-wrap").prop("disabled",true);
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('inactive-menu')) {
        slideRight();
        deactivate();
    } else {
        slideLeft();
        activate();
    }

setTimeout(function(){setFunction()},500); //
});
}

//*************THIS FUNCTION HAS A CONFILCT WITH THE ONE ABOVE****************
jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = jQuery("#mobile-menu-wrap");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        slideRight();
        deactivate();
    }
});
```

CODEPEN FORK: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvAle

Comment: Why you bind identical callbacks to the same element?

Comment: I didn't really develop that part of the code on my own. it was a suggestion from someone. If you could help restructure it, I'm open to it.

Comment: Well, for me this code is working good. What you mean "conflict"?

Comment: It is mostly working. There is one bug - go to the codepen page, make sure you have your browser window larger than 1024px to start --> Click on the page --> shrink browser width below 1024px. The menu will show up entirely. It's only supposed to show the toggler button.

Comment: Hm, it's show toggler button for me

Comment: I have clear your code a bit, to understand completely what you want to achieve. Te main problem with your code is that it have very tricky logic for menu state toggling. It's would be hard to maintain and feature, and could have more troubles. http://jsbin.com/wetug/1/ I recommend you to track the state of menu, and didn't use `toggle`. It's will make your code more clear. Also, it's looks redundant to use `off`.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i probably done it [like this](http://jsbin.com/wetug/4) (just example)